# How to use angular.element().bind with dynamically generated element id

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have element with randomly generated id, and my question is how i can access it from controller, my code is like this.

```
self.componentId = '#' + Math.random().toString();

angular.element(self.componentId).bind('scroll', function () {
    if (angular.element(this).scrollTop() + angular.element(this).innerHeight() >= angular.element(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        console.log('testing 123');
    }
});
```

and on html element i have

```
<div id={{$ctrl.componentId}}></div>
```

My question is simple, what i need to change on function above to make it see scroll event. If i pass in angular.element('#hardcodedId'), then it work...

Comment: In the AngularJS framework, element events are bound to functions by using Angular directives, either core directives or custom directives. For more information, see [AngularJS Developers Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). As the directive is attached to the element itself, there is no need to know the element id.

Answer (score 0):

that's because `<div id={{$ctrl.componentId}}></div>` is not evaluated immidiately after `self.componentId = '#' + Math.random().toString();`, but when angular starts the digest cycle

I see two solutions to your problem: either bind inside `$timeout`, which will postpone until digest cycle starts, or add a `class` to your element so that it can be bound before setting its `id`

if I were you I'd do it the second way

Comment: It's not working, my problem is i have no idea how to pass dynamic string (element id) here angular.element(HERE)

Comment: there is also another problem with your code, `id` in HTML cannot start with a number